# QGIS Formatting LineString

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

I'm trying to visualize some directional depth slices and I'm having some trouble getting QGIS to render the lines like I want and it's been driving me crazy.

I have a python script that outputs my intermediate output as LINESTRING in the following format:

```
id;wkt
0;LINESTRING(p1,p2,p3,.....p800)
1;LINESTRING(p801,p802,....p1600)
....
```

and then I import the file using Layer -> Add Layer -> Add delimited text layer and selecting WKT and the appropriate options.  I then change the layer properties to show arrows, because I'd like to see the direction of the lines.

The issue is that QGIS is drawing these enormous circles - it appears to be connecting the beginning and the ends of each line together through some kind of "enormous circle" algorithm.  I'd really, really love to get rid of these circles and just see the lines.

[image]

Comment: OK, I've figured it out - I had a point on the beginning of my line that belonged on the other end and QGIS was connecting the points with the circles.  Removing the point removed the arrows and it's displaying properly now.

Comment: How did you change the layer direction to show arrows?